# getting error of character string buffer too small even after changing to varchar(32000)

Tags: oracle, plsql

getting error  QRA-06502  of character string buffer too small even after changing to varchar(32000)

```
create or replace function product_purchase(CUSTOMER_COD VARCHAR2) return varchar is
    CODE VARCHAR2(32000);
   
BEGIN
    CODE := ' ';

   
    FOR PRODUCTS_INFO IN (SELECT CUSTOMER_CODE,PRODUCT_NAME
                            FROM ORDER_DETAIL JOIN ORDERS
                          ON ORDER_DETAIL.ORDER_ID = ORDERS.ORDER_ID)
                            LOOP
                            CODE := CODE || PRODUCTS_INFO.CUSTOMER_CODE||PRODUCTS_INFO.PRODUCT_NAME ||',';
                            END LOOP;
                            RETURN CODE;
                            END product_purchase;
                            /
```

ERROR MAINLY OCCURS WHILE SELECTING DATA AND PUTTING IT IN THE FUNCTION

```
SELECT CUSTOMER_CODE ,product_purchase(CUSTOMER_CODE),COUNT(PRODUCT_NAME)
                            FROM ORDER_DETAIL JOIN ORDERS
                          ON ORDER_DETAIL.ORDER_ID = ORDERS.ORDER_ID
                            GROUP BY CUSTOMER_CODE,product_purchase(CUSTOMER_CODE)
                          HAVING COUNT(PRODUCT_NAME)=3;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even after changing to `varchar2(32000)`? Well, that doesn't guarantee that you'll get the result (obviously).

The way I see it, it is cursor query that is wrong. If you're calling a function as

```
product_purchase(CUSTOMER_CODE)
```

it means that you're passing a **parameter** to it (you didn't post the whole function code so I'll presume that parameter's name is `par_customer_code`; note that it shouldn't be just `customer_code` as it is equal to column name and you'll get unexpected result once you use the parameter).

Exactly - **use the parameter**. Code you wrote doesn't use it. Should've been

```
SELECT CUSTOMER_CODE,PRODUCT_NAME
FROM ORDER_DETAIL JOIN ORDERS
ON ORDER_DETAIL.ORDER_ID = ORDERS.ORDER_ID
WHERE customer_code = par_customer_code           --> this
```

I guess that - applying that change - you won't have problems.

---

However, if you do, then check whether code you wrote actually *works*, run the cursor query itself and see how many rows it returns. Then, restrict number of rows. How? A simple way is to use `rownum`:

```
SELECT CUSTOMER_CODE,PRODUCT_NAME
FROM ORDER_DETAIL JOIN ORDERS
ON ORDER_DETAIL.ORDER_ID = ORDERS.ORDER_ID
WHERE customer_code = par_customer_code
  AND rownum <= 10;                            --> this
```

and run your code again.

If it works, and if it turns out that `varchar2` isn't capable of storing that much data, use **CLOB** datatype instead:

```
DECLARE
  CODE CLOB;        --> this
```

Comment: Notice: `clob` [cannot](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/adlob/LOB-restrictions.html#GUID-BA662EA5-4955-4582-B12E-3312FE4B1D6A) be a part of the `group by` as in original statement. So the original query should be redesigned in case of `clob` return datatype

Comment: Thank you, @astentx. I **hope** that CLOB won't have to be used at all; it is all about the parameter that is missing (at least, I believe so).

Comment: I edited the query because while submitting i forgot to add some main lines can you tell me whats wrong now

Comment: cursor runs totally fines seperatly but I only need 5 rows from it using function 5 customer code which order 3 products

Comment: Once again: you never used the parameter in cursor FOR loop's query.